# Apple Animation in React with inline CSS problem

Tags: html, css, reactjs, typescript, scss-mixins

I try to recreate this animation with HTML and CSS in React with Typescript using inline styling.I am creating an object with styling information, and refer to it in the style attribute. The code is down below. It does not work and I am not sure what I am doing wrong, I suspect the styles are not defined and referred correctly?

Here is the original Codepen example I try to rewrite: [Apple Animation](https://codepen.io/alvaromontoro/pen/RmRjvg)

And here is my code

```
import React from 'react';

const styles = {
    
    '@keyframes showTopText': {
        '0%': { transform: 'translate3d(0, 100%, 0)' },
        '40%, 60%': { transform: 'translate3d(0, 50%, 0)' },
        '100%': { transform: 'translate3d(0, 0, 0)' },
    },
    '@keyframes showBottomText': {
        '0%': { transform: 'translate3d(0, -100%, 0)' },
        '100%': { transform: 'translate3d(0, 0, 0)' },
    },

    animatedTitle: {
        color: '#222',
        fontFamily: 'Roboto, Arial, sans-serif',
        height: '90vmin',
        left: '50%',
        top: '50%',
        transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
        width: '90vmin',
    },
    'animatedTitle > div': {
        height: '50%',
        overflow: 'hidden',
        position: 'absolute',
        width: '100%',
    },
    'animatedTitle > div div': {
        fontSize: '12vmin',
        padding: '2vmin 0',
        position: 'absolute',
    },
    'animatedTitle > div div span': {
        display: 'block',
    },
    'animated-title > div.text-top': {
        borderBottom: '1vmin solid #000',
        top: 0,
    },
    'animatedTitle > div.text-top div': {
        animation: 'showTopText 1s',
        animationDelay: '0.5s',
        animationFillMode: 'forwards',
        bottom: 0,
        transform: 'translate(0, 100%)',
    },
    'animatedTitle > div.text-top div span:first-child': {
        color: '#767676',
    },
    'animatedTitle > div.text-bottom': {
        bottom: 0,
    },
    'animatedTitle > div.text-bottom div': {
        animation: 'showBottomText 0.5s',
        animationDelay: '1.75s',
        animationFillMode: 'forwards',
        top: 0,
        transform: 'translate(0, -100%)',
    },
};

function Design() {
    return (
        <div style={styles.animatedTitle}>
            <div style={styles['animatedTitle > div.text-top div']}>
                <div>
                    <span>mimicking</span>
                    <span>apple's design</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style={styles['animatedTitle > div.text-bottom']}>
                <div>for the win!</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export { Design };
```

Comment: My code in Codepen: https://codepen.io/Figario/pen/RwMGabd?editors=1010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `styled-components` to keep your component more flexible and compatible. I replicated the **codepen** example with `styled-components` and made it easily extensible.

So, `TopAnimateBlock` and `BottomAnimateBlock` have **numOfLine** property hence how many lines is inside the block. The second property in `BottomAnimateBlock` is  **delayTopLine**, it should have the same numbers as a **numOfLine** in `TopAnimateBlock`, because we need to wait for top lines to play.

Also you can easily change the text color with **color** property in `TextStyle` and pass as color value, **HEX** color or **rgba()** / **hsla()**.

#### TextAnimation.tsx

```js
import styled, { keyframes } from 'styled-components';

const showTopText = keyframes`
  0% { transform: translate3d(0, 100% , 0); }
  40%, 60% { transform: translate3d(0, 50%, 0); }
  100% { transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); }
`;
const showBottomText = keyframes`
  0% { transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0); }
  100% { transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); }
`;

const Section = styled.section`
  width: calc(100% + 10vmin);
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  padding: 2vmin 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  &:last-child {
    border-top: 1vmin solid white;
  }
`;

const Block = styled.div<{ numOfLine: number }>`
  position: relative;
`;
const TopAnimateBlock = styled(Block)`
  animation: ${showTopText} calc(0.5s * ${props => props.numOfLine}) forwards;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
  transform: translateY(calc(100% * ${props => props.numOfLine}));
`;
const BottomAnimateBlock = styled(Block)<{ delayTopLine: number }>`
  animation: ${showBottomText} calc(0.5s * ${props => props.numOfLine}) forwards;
  animation-delay: calc(0.7s * ${props => props.delayTopLine});
  transform: translateY(calc(-100% * ${props => props.numOfLine}));
`;

const TextStyle = styled.p<{ color: string }>`
  font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12vmin;
  color: ${props => props.color};
`;

export const TextAnimation = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Section>
        <TopAnimateBlock numOfLine={2}>
          <TextStyle color="grey">mimicking</TextStyle>
          <TextStyle color="white">apple's design</TextStyle>
        </TopAnimateBlock>
      </Section>
      <Section>
        <BottomAnimateBlock numOfLine={1} delayTopLine={2}>
          <TextStyle color="white">for the win!</TextStyle>
        </BottomAnimateBlock>
      </Section>
    </>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit dazziling-code]

##### If we want to animate 3 lines instead of 2, just add / change:

1. Add new `TextStyle` component
2. Change from 2 to 3 **numOfLine** in `TopAnimateBlock` and **delayTopLine** in `BottomAnimateBlock`
3. And replace keyframes to this fragment:

```js
const showTopText = keyframes`
  0% { transform: translate3d(0, 100% , 0); }
  25%, 40% { transform: translate3d(0, 66%, 0); }
  60%, 75% { transform: translate3d(0, 33%, 0); }
  100% { transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); }
`;
```